# How does TomTom store trackpoint information on its internal drive?

Tags: gps

How does TomTom stores tracks and trackpoints on its internal drive? I maintain an open source computer forensics tool and would like to extract the data from both files and unallocated space. My experience with Garmin GPS devices is that they all use the same internal data format, and I suspect that TomTom devices do the same.

Comment: Which tomtom device?

Comment: I clarified the question. My belief is t hat they all use the same internal structure.

Comment: See old manual http://www.tomtom.com/lib/doc/ttnavsdk3_manual.pdf or the Maptool Kit SDK http://developer.tomtom.com/docs/read/Map_Toolkit

Comment: That's great. Thanks. I also found that http://www.gpsbabel.org/ appears to have an implementation of the binary reader. If this question wasn't on hold you could submit your answer and I could accept it...

Comment: Can you post a link to the TomTom audit report? I did a lot of research but was not able to find it. I need the prove that TomTom uses public key cryptography for the triplog files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main types of TomTom PNDs. The first generation uses the TomTom HOME application, and are plain USB mass storage devices - they contain files. The second generation uses the MyTomTom website, and are networked devices - they use HTTP.

On the latter, you simply won't get any data off. That's by design. On the former, you could get the tracks off, but they're encrypted. Public key/private key, and the device only has the public key. TomTom has a audit report to prove that. The usual circumvention is that the police shows up at TomTom with a device and a court order, but that won't work for you. *By design*.

If you mean an itinerary (a set of waypoints that you can choose at once), those are stored in *.itn files. There are plenty of tools capable of reading those. But that's forensically not very interesting, "DutchWindmills.itn" isn't going to convict someone.

Comment: That's very interesting. So there is no way to view the tracks and trackpoints from the TomTom device itself?

Comment: The tracks that you've travelled? No. (You're using a term taht's not common in the industry). The routes travelled are stored only for the map improvement program. Also, since that's the only use, they're pre-processed for anonymity. In particular, they're generally not complete.

Comment: Sorry for using the incorrect term. Garmin GPS devices allow you to turn on `Trip Log` `Show` on the config screen. When you enable it, the GPS reads the `*.gpx` files and displays the content of the XML `gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension` tags. So I reasonably expected that I was displaying tracks...